# How to find the permissions used by dependencies? - Android

Tags: android, google-play, android-permissions, google-play-console

I'm trying to upload my Android app to the Play Store, but keep being refused because of background location permission: "***Feature does not meet requirements for background location access***".

My manifest declares ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, but **does not** include ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION. As my app target API 30 and the minimum API is 29 I am not implicitly using background location.

Yet, when I upload my app in the Play Store I can see that my bundle includes android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION which leaves me to believe that some dependency in my app is using this permission.

Is this possible? If so, how could I find which is?

Comment: Go to manifest at the bottom you will find the merged manifest checkout the manifest of the library remove the permission and build the app.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Since I'm using Xamarin it wasn't exactly the same, but because you told me it was called "merged manifest" I found what I was looking for. 

For xamarin user look in the properties of your project, there you'll find the manifest and another file called AssemblyInfo. In AssemblyInfo.cs you should find the equivalent of the merged manifest. 

In my case I was looking for "[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.AccessBackgroundLocation)]".

Comment: Also the real merged manifest (final) is available at your_project/obj/releaseOrDebug/version_number/android/manifest/AndroidManifest.xml. It is generated after you build your app and is availble either in the release or the debug folder according to what your settings were when you built.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes we do need to list all permissions introduced by our dependencies. Here is the script I wrote to do this. Add this script to your app build.gradle,

```
import com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension
import com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApplicationVariantImpl
import com.android.build.gradle.internal.publishing.AndroidArtifacts

// Gradle script to list permissions of dependencies.
def androidExtension = project.extensions.findByType(AppExtension.class)
if (androidExtension != null) {
    project.afterEvaluate {
        tasks.register('listpermissions') {
            doFirst {
                androidExtension.applicationVariants.forEach {
                    def variantData = (it as ApplicationVariantImpl).variantData
                    def manifests = variantData.variantDependencies.getArtifactCollection(
                            AndroidArtifacts.ConsumedConfigType.RUNTIME_CLASSPATH,
                            AndroidArtifacts.ArtifactScope.ALL,
                            AndroidArtifacts.ArtifactType.MANIFEST)
                    println("================================================================================================")
                    println('| LIST PERMISSIONS FOR ' + it.name)
                    manifests.forEach { manifest ->
                        if (manifest.file.exists()) {
                            def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(manifest.file.text)
                            def usesPermissions = xml.'uses-permission'
                            if (usesPermissions.size() > 0) {
                                println("| LIBRARY: " + manifest.file.parentFile.name + ' (' + usesPermissions.size() + ')')
                                usesPermissions.each { println("| PERMISSION: " + it.'@android:name') }
                                println("================================================================================================")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then run the gradle task by `gradlew :app:listpermissions` to list all permission used by each dependecy. For example,

```
================================================================================================
| LIST PERMISSIONS FOR googleRelease
| LIBRARY: jetified-vmlib-3.0.3 (1)
| PERMISSION: android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
================================================================================================
| LIBRARY: jetified-matisse-1.3.1 (2)
| PERMISSION: android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
| PERMISSION: android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
================================================================================================
| LIBRARY: biometric-1.1.0 (2)
| PERMISSION: android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC
| PERMISSION: android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT
================================================================================================
| LIBRARY: jetified-vmlib-network-3.0.1 (2)
| PERMISSION: android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
| PERMISSION: android.permission.INTERNET
================================================================================================
....
```

Comment: Tried ran the script. seems like Execution failed for task ':app:listpermissions'.
> No such property: variantDependencies for class: com.android.build.gradle.internal.variant.ApplicationVariantData